# Major Project Suggestion

Tags: computer-science, project

I'm in the final year of computer science and engineering. I'm looking for ideas about a year long project,which is of great importance in my curriculum. So, I'm looking for a topic,that is not very simple but which can be implemented within a year.

My interests are

1. Data Mining
2. Distributed Computing
3. Data Structures and Algorithms
4. Neural Networks

Also, I'm open to suggestions regarding the same for any other field that could be of value to me, as I'm interested in higher studies post my bachelor's degree.

I want to improve my coding skills , so I'm interested in doing the implementation in C++/Java.

Please help me with some advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, Machine learning (which is very close to Neural networks). It is one of the emerging areas where things are happening, ...

As an example, a simple Bayesian can be used as a spam filter.
SVM (Support Vector Machine), many believe is the best machine around.

All the above are just algorithms, for a particular type of problem, like say,
- Stock market prediction
- Medical diagnosis
- AGV (Automatic Guided vehicles) etc etc ..

So,

Step-1: Decide on some interesting topic,
Step-2: Decide on some (relatively) challenging algorithms
Step-3: Implement and enjoy ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion..
I myself found the topic of machine learning very interesting as I was browsing through the web.But as I have never taken a course in it, could you please provide me some pointers as to how I can explore more about it, or could you please suggest a couple of problems that can be implemented within a year??

Comment: Stanford provides an online course on machine learning ... check out the following link http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is free ...

Answer (score 1):

[Create an application that can predict tomorrow's stock market level with  100% accuracy](https://superuser.com/questions/13741/what-kind-of-software-are-you-looking-for-but-is-impossible-to-find/13746#13746).

Stock market is full of data, and determining the relationship between prices are plain hard. Which is why you need to use neural network to train on the large sets of data, maybe over a dozens of computers.

It should be a challenging project.

Comment: The stock market price is set by human expectation of what that price should be. The only way to perfectly predict the stock market is to predict how everyone that invests in it feels.

Comment: It's not challenging, it's provably impossible using only stock market data.  As Joeri said above, the Stock Market is a reactive metric of how the investors think and feel, and that is based on a lot more than just "what was yesterdays stock market".  If the Fed Chairman announces tonight that he is drastically raising the prime rate, the market will plummet as soons as it opens.  But nor progam with only Stock Market data could predict that.  It would also have ot be able to read and understand a newsfeed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a social network.

:-D

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a KDD project for me :)
since the NetFlix winner's algorithms are not out, you might want to implement the blended algorithms outlined in the Progress Prizes:

http://www.netflixprize.com/assets/ProgressPrize2008_BellKor.pdf

and

http://www.netflixprize.com/assets/ProgressPrize2008_BigChaos.pdf

more here:

http://netflixkddworkshop2008.info/accepted.html

Answer (score 0):

Something a firm had to do that I worked at once was to calculate the distance/drive time from every postcode sector to every other one forming a matrix that then allowed lookups of the data later on.

This used Djikstra's algorithm, required a custom datastructure to hold road information during the processing and required a sensible output file to allow the lookups later on. Because the task was so large though they had to run this over a small hive of computers, which is where the distributed networking stuff comes in. Maybe you could so something similar?

Answer (score 0):

given those, I'd take the Lucene project (or CLucene) as a start point and build a product on top of it. Search is pretty passe nowadays, but doing more interesting things with the results could be very interesting to your tutor.

Don't try to reinvent anything though, take something and build upon it.